# Embedding SQL server express 2005 with my application

Tags: c#, installation, setup-deployment

How can I embed Sql server 2005 express edition with my Setup package as one file?

Thanks.

P.S:It's a Windows Application.

Comment: Please clarify on whether you are looking to run SQLExpress Embedded in your app or simply creating a deployment package that contains your app and SQL Express?

Comment: I need to Embed it. Not just include it along with the package as a seperate file to be installed automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562.aspx for embedding instructions.

Don't let the "Using a Wrapper" section intimidate...You won't need that.  But you will need the command line switches.  The installer is a single executable that can be fired off from your main installer, and the command line switches provide all of the control you will need for a successful installation.

See also here:

Configuring SQL Express During Installation http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2006/09/20/763956.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Well technically, to really embed a database, you'd have to use something like SqlCe, SQLite, etc. SQL Express still runs as a service, so I don't know if you can really embed it.